# Spark make a computation, but give a null output

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

i try to execute an example to find friends with python 3 and pyspark

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

file = "D:\\jsonFIle\\Live.txt"
out_file = "D:\\jsonFIle\\friends.txt"

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Common Friends").setMaster("local").set("spark.driver.memory", "5g")

#sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()

f = sc.textFile(file)

def check(line):
    if len(line.split()) > 1:
           return len((line.split())[1].split(',')) > 1
    return False

adlists = f.filter(check).map(lambda line: line.split()).persist()
adlists = adlists.map(lambda l: (l[0], l[1].split(','))).persist()

def form_pairs(tup):
    l = []
    for elem1 in tup[1]:
        for elem2 in tup[1]:
            if elem1 < elem2:
                l.append(((elem1, elem2), 1))
    return l

pairs = adlists.flatMap(form_pairs)

cf = pairs.reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x + y)
sim = sorted(cf.collect())

out = open(out_file, "w")
for tuple in sim:
    s = str(tuple[0][0]) + "," + str(tuple[0][1]) + "\t" + str(tuple[1]) + "\n"
    out.write(s)
out.close()

print("done")
```

This is an example, so i know that must work. 
I installed pyspark following a guide online https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/install-spark-on-windows-pyspark-4498a5d8d66c

and if i run on anaconda prompt "pyspark" start directly jupyter and when import pyspark i dont have any problem.

on anaconda prompt i see this log

```
[IPKernelApp] WARNING | Unknown error in handling PYTHONSTARTUP file C:\opt\spark\spark-2.2.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\shell.py:
[I 21:47:47.447 NotebookApp] Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel 6d4c3d50-648f-4d2d-858b-5df642386e14
[Stage 0:=========================>                               (15 + 8) / 33][I 21:49:28.441 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Downloads/ProvaSpark.ipynb
[I 21:51:28.434 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Downloads/ProvaSpark.ipynb
[Stage 2:===>                                                      (2 + 8) / 33][I 22:03:28.929 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Downloads/ProvaSpark.ipynb
[I 22:05:28.916 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Downloads/ProvaSpark.ipynb
[I 22:09:28.917 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Downloads/ProvaSpark.ipynb
```

I see during the execution that stage 0 and 2 increase during computation, and when finish stop. My output file is blank, and i dont understand why.

My friend try on his machine, and working, but sometimes have error and must restart Jupyter kernel and execute more time before have a right computation.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved.

It was simply a dataset problem, which had included a header in the text file and the program could not pars it.